# Is it required for a HTML Table to have the same number of columns in all rows?

Tags: html

In other words: is this violating any spec? Or is there any reason to avoid that?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> c11 </td>
    <td> c12 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> c21 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(I know that there is colspan attribute, this is not what I am asking)

Comment: No, you can skip it but the result can be unexpected. I think all browser will display it incorrectly.

Comment: @BobS The table will not display properly, that's all! it would look like a brick wall missing one of the bricks (provided the table has a border)!

Comment: @Si8: I'd expect it to be rendered as here in this page. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Yes you are correct and what i say incorrectly, I just meant it won't be like how you would expect. Not that the browser will throw an error or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [w3c specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#column-calc) for HTML tables, under **Calculating the number of columns in a table**:

> The number of columns is equal to the number of columns required by the row with the most columns, including cells that span multiple columns. For any row that has fewer than this number of columns, the end of that row should be padded with empty cells.

So no, each row does not need to have the same number of columns. The browser should handle it, as it follows the standard.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

No it is not, you can use the colspan attribute as in

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```